# Return minimum sum of amounts in sql query that are greater than amount

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
+----+--------+
| id | amount |
+----+--------+
|  1 |     20 |
|  2 |     30 |
|  3 |     10 |
|  4 |     50 |
|  5 |      5 |
+----+--------+
```

If I have a value say `set @amount = 75;` I want to get the ids of the largest `amount`s that fill the amount. So in this case it would be the `id`s: would be `4,2` even though this sums to `80`.

Pseudo code:

1. pop largest value in set <= `@amount` and put id in `arr`
2. if sum is < `@amount` go to step 1.
3. print `arr`

Comment: haha I am trying!

Comment: What if the amount was 45?  Or 54?

Comment: 45 would be `2,1` and 54 would be `4,2`

Comment: does the psuedo code not help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, sum(amount) over (order by amount desc, id) as running_amount
      from t
     ) t
where running_amount - amount < 75;
```

In pre 8.0 versions of MySQL, one method is a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (select sum(t2.amount) from t t2 where t2.amount <= t.amount) as running_amount
      from t
     ) t
where running_amount - amount < 75;
```

Comment: I am getting the syntax error:
> MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(order by amount_nbr desc, id) as running_amount from part where hol

Comment: am I replacing all the `t`s with my own table or just the nested ones?

Comment: I have never seen the keyword `over` before not sure it is working!

Comment: the nested query `select t.*, sum(amount) over (order by amount desc, id) as running_amount
      from t` does not work when replacing `t` with my table

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your usecase, may be this could be done by something like:

```sql
SELECT 
 GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR ',') AS ids
 SUM(t.amount)
FROM (
   SELECT 
    id as id,
    'group' as group,
    amount as amount
   FROM you_table
   WHERE amount <= @amount
   ORDER BY amount DESC
   LIMIT 2) as t
GROUP BY t.group
```

else you'll need to use Cursor in a stored procedure:

```
DECLARE total;
DECLARE my_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT id, amount FROM yourTable ORDER BY amount DESC;
DECLARE c_amount;
DECLARE c_id;
SET total = 0;
OPEN my_cursor;
counter_loop: WHILE total <= mount DO
  FETCH cursor_name INTO c_id, c_amount;
  set total = total + c_amount;
END counter_loop
CLOSE my_cursor;
```

Code hasn't been checked and is simple out of mind. Hope this can help.

Comment: limiting by 2 is cheating :) can't use stored procedures unfortunately!

Comment: also `'group' as group` seems to be throwing issues

Comment: @maxisme ```'group' as group``` will of course throw, because group is a reserved key word (didn't thought about that). But it should work as ```'group' as `group` ```